# Monit - stop receiving emails about monit reload

Tags: linux, monit

Is there any way to stop receiving e-mails about reloading "monit" service?

This is current config in /etc/monit.d/config (and mydomain.com is my machine):

*

```
check system mydomain.com
check process script_name with pidfile /home/user/scripts/script-pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/script_name start" with timeout 60 seconds
stop program  = "/etc/init.d/script_name stop"
set alert my_email@domain.com
set mail-format { from: monit@mydomain.com }
set mailserver smtp.mydomain.com,localhost
set mail-format {
    from: monit@mydomain.com
    subject: [ $SERVICE ] $EVENT - $DATE
    message: This is $ACTION: $DESCRIPTION [$SERVICE], mydomain.com }
set httpd port 2812 and
     use address localhost  # only accept connection from localhost
     allow localhost        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
     allow admin:monit      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
```

*

But since I am having logrotation every hour which is reloading services, monit is sending e-mails every hour:

*This is start: Monit reloaded [system_localhost.localdomain], mydomain.com*

*This is stop: Monit stopped [mydomain.com], mydomain.com*

How to stop receiving those e-mails about monit (which I don't want to receive)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By default, monit will alert for every action, but luckily, it also allows you to set the event filter, so you don't receive alerts as frequently as you do.

You can set the event filter to only send alerts when your process does not exist like this:

```
set alert my_email@domain.com only on { nonexist }
```

For a full list of available events and setting a filter, check the documentation: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-event-filter

Answer (score 0):

To receive all alerts except notification about Monit program start and stop:

```
set alert my_email@domain.com not {instance}
```